# Set floor/round value sql value

Tags: sql, sqlite, garrys-mod

I'm developing a bank system for Garry's Mod (GLua) using sql for it. I want to create a "profit" that adds a percentage to every player every minute:
The sql query is this one:

```
UPDATE 
     darkrp_player 
SET 
     bank = bank * "..multiplier
```

This is what it returns when running that query on DBBrowser:

```
no such function: floor: UPDATE darkrp_player SET bank = floor(bank * 1.25)
```

multiplier var is (profit/100) + 1 profit is another var

So my problem is that everytime I run that query, every bank row is full of decimals, example:

```
profit = 25
--before query:
'bank' = 2
--after query:
'bank' = 2.5
```

My question is: How can I set floor to the value I'm setting to 'bank'? I could get everybody's 'bank' value and set it one by one, but that would be really really complicated... So, i'm looking something like

```
UPDATE 
     darkrp_player 
SET 
     bank = floor(bank * "..multiplier..")"
```

I'm sorry if you haven't understood something, you can ask me whatever related to my problem, I'll be glad to answer you. THANKS!

Comment: `floor()` works.  Did you try it?

Comment: Sure! I tried it: SET bank = floor(bank * multiplier)

Comment: It returns to me: no such function: floor: UPDATE darkrp_player SET bank = floor(bank * 1.25)

Comment: are you sure that is exactly what it says... floor is a function in sql -- what version are you using?

Comment: The sql servers is built-in a server of Garry'sMod (game) as a library. [GLua wiki SQL LIBRARY](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:sql)

Comment: @AlexParedes - it uses an sql engine called sqlite... so you can google that for documentation.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know it was called sqlite, I searched sqlite floor function and appeared what Denis Reznik showed me (CAST function). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no FLOOR function on that built-in server, try this:

```
SELECT CAST('67.896' AS int),  CAST('5.57' AS int)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to SELECT, I want to SET

Comment: @AlexParedes -- this is an example -- try it if it works use it in the set.

Comment: @AlexParedes UPDATE darkrp_player SET bank = CAST(CAST(bank * "..multiplier AS decimal) AS int)

Comment: It worked, thank you! I tried CONVERT but didn't work, thanks for showing me CAST function!

Comment: @AlexParedes due to the fact that you post this question to the SQL Server topic first, I suppose that maybe you use a really old version of SQL Server, that is why I propose this solution. As for SQLite, looks like the query can a bit simpler: CAST('67.896' AS int). I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

```
--declaring variable table for example
declare @x table (value real)

--inserting some dummy values in variable table
insert into @x (value)
select '12.45'
union
select '56.789'

select * from @x

--updating variable table values using floor function
--floor function Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression
update @x set value = floor(value)

select * from @x
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I understood nothing...